# Angular build prod error "Property is private and only accessible"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

While I am trying to do `build --prod` from my page I was getting few error this error where bit confusing.

For example:

```
Property 'selectedSize' is private and only accessible within class 'EditorComponent'.

<select id="dimension-preset" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedSize">

Property 'size' is private and only accessible within class 'EditorComponent'.

<input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="size.width" (keyup)="changeSize()"/>
```

How can I solve this?

This is my html:

```
  <select id="dimension-preset" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedSize"
      (ngModelChange)="changeToPreset($event)">
       <option value="null">Requirements</option>
          <option *ngFor="let s of sizes" [ngValue]="s">{{s.width}}x{{s.height}}</option>
  </select>
```

This is my html for size

```
     <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="size.width" (keyup)="changeSize()"/>
     <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

This is my TS:

```
private selectedSize: any = null;

    private size: any = {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
  };
```

Comment: Properties the view needs access to should be marked as public.

Comment: can i change it to public

Comment: sure!  Also, you might find [this explanation](https://medium.com/@erVikas1/angular-and-typescript-public-properties-a5a3c363b790) useful.

Comment: @BizzyBob thanks i have one more query 

Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

126                       <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="size.height" (keyup)="changeSize()"/>

    changeSize(event: any): void {
        this.canvas.setWidth(this.size.width);
        this.canvas.setHeight(this.size.height);
    } 

how to solve this

Comment: This is saying your `changeSize()` method is expecting you to pass the event.  You can do this like: `changeSize($event)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two ways to fix

1. Remove private on your .ts file
   or
2. Or you can change private to public,
   I would prefer first one because its more clear